# Javascript: Find all indices of timestamp substrings

Tags: javascript, substring

With "X" being a number, I would like to find all the occurrences of sub-strings in the format of

- `"XX:XX:XX" || "XX:XX" || "X:XX"`
- (hour):(minute):(second)

within a paragraph for further manipulation. Besides looping, are there more elegant ways?

Notes:

- The timestamp may or may not have spaces before/after the sub-string (e.g. in Asian text).
- The timestamp sub-string might appear several times within a sentence.

Comment: So what have you tried so far? Please add your code

Comment: This sounds like a good use-case for a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Answer (score 2):

You could match two groups of all or parts.

```js
const
    time = /\d\d:\d\d:\d\d|\d?\d:\d\d/g,
    string = 'abc1:23def12:34ghi12:34:56jkl98:7abc1:23def12:34ghi12:34:56jkl',
    result = string.match(time);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

That's what regexes are for:

```
/(\d{1,2}):(\d{2})(?::(\d{2}))?/g
```

Inspect on [Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/lT3xHa/1)

You can then use it with any of the regex methods, e.g. `.matchAll`:

```js
console.log(Array.from('asd50:foo 12:27 bar13:49:21baz 5:41'.matchAll(/(\d{1,2}):(\d{2})(?::(\d{2}))?/g)))
```

For more exact timestamp matching (e.g. no `35:70:99`), you can use some regex wizardry (note that it uses a lookbehind, that's new in ES2018):

```
/(?<!\d|:)([01]?\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]\d)(?::([0-5]\d))?(?!\d|:)/g
```

Inspect on [Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/2v0n5u/2)

Comment: Thanks for the extra sanity check!